# I get "Undefined rate from NNN-USD"

Tags: concurrency, magento2

I don't have a currency converter setup. **Base Currency** is NNN, **Default Display Currency** is NNN and **Allowed Currencies** is also NNN. I can't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Hi Kovalski, what is your Magento version? Is this happened when you newly install the project for first time or is it worked earlier?

Comment: Hi, I have 2.3.4 version and yes it have worked before. I have not yet lounched, so i tried making orders before to check if everything is fine and it was. Then I added some plugins for importing and tweaked in settings some general stuff and tried making orders again but it says that the rate is undefined. Which is strange because I am using only one currency in allowed currency. Maybe there are some hidden settings that affect currency?

Comment: Was it work correctly before installed third party plugins? If so I think some of plugin’s configurations might be affected to default Magento currency settings. One solution is re-try it after disabled all the installed third party plugins and re-enable those one by one and see the result. If you would find the issue with a plugin then you’ll have to debug that plugin’s code and identify the root cause where it affected to currency. Normally, default Magento code base should be worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for sugestio, I will try that and post an update if it was the problem. Is it enough just to disable them? Could they affect aomething even if disabled.

Comment: Anytime Kovalski! I think you will have to re-index and clear the cache after disabled plugins and try it in incognito mode to see the changes.

Comment: @DasithaAbeysinghe Yup, it was an extension. I'll try to sort it with its vendor. Fixed it by simply disabling the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with an extension that messed up order code. I figured it by disabling one by one extension as@DasithaAbeysinghe suggested.